# Passing parameters to a python script using SL4A on Android

Tags: android, python, sl4a

I am trying to get a Python script which I normally run on my PC to run on my Android phone (HTC Hero). I have SL4A running on my phone and have made a few tweaks to the Python script so that this does now run. The problem that I am having is how to pass parameters to the script. I have tried creating a sh script in SL4A which called the python file with the parameters, but this didn't work. I have also tried using the app TaskBomb to call through to the python file, but again this doesn't work when parameters are supplied. When no params are supplied the file loads correctly, but when I add -h to the filename it says it can no longer find the python file I am calling.

Is anybody able to provide assistance with how to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a round about method to circumvent the problem. First the python script needs to be modified to look for a text file containing the attributes. Now whenever I need to start the script, i have to push the txt file containing the attributes and then start the script.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest modifying the script to call  getDialogInput.

```
import android
app = android.Android()
response = app.dialogGetInput(Title, Message, Default_Values).result
```

Then set whatever variable the script expects the parameters to be in to response.

Ive done this and also modified a script to get the android clipboard instead of taking input directly. You could always make several versions of the script with hard coded parameters.

Hope this helps as im pretty new to python and sl4a.

Comment: I formatted your code part in the question, next time, please do it (simply by marking the relevant code and pressing `ctrl+k` or `cmd+k` on a mac

Comment: I will remember to do that in the future. At first when I looked at my answer I thought it happened magically. Thank you.